# what happens if submit a form without input names?

Tags: html, forms, input, names

I know it's a stupid question, but if I fill a form with various inputs but I don't give them a name and id, and I POST it to a php page, does the posted query contain any data?

If it does, then using inputs without names in a form result in a wasted sending time. am I right?

Is there any difference between GET and POST in this case?
I presume that the browser (client-side) determines what to send and what to not send.

I'll try to see what happens if i send a GET request: if in the browser bar appear something, some data has been sent.

But the POST method is still a mistery for me... when I have time I'll try to print the $_POST array. thanks for the "input" @MattP

I update my question after somebody attack: I printed down the result of $_POST and $_GET, but still, I think the only answer to my question is to check the weight of the data, not the things recognized by the server. If i send unnamed data to the server, the server may discard that ad take only the ones with the name.

*(sorry for the bad english)*

Comment: The form contains all the data, but the page on the server will try to get the field values by their names and since those names are not present in the form the server gets undefined or null values.

Comment: You only need a name attribute to appear in the POST request.  I'd expect no data to be passed so you will get an empty array.  Try it though by using print_r($_POST) to confirm;

Comment: Why didn't you test it yourself and look at the results?

Comment: @Bondye, I haven't time to do everything: if anyone has the answer, _he/she's welcome_. I don't know deeply how the POST and GET works and there's no a lot of answer about their efficiency online, so i do question ;)

Comment: It is just a simple test case like this: http://codepad.viper-7.com/5UsGF2 StackOverflow is not for debugging, testing or writing tutorials. It is for helping people with a problem.

Comment: @Bondye I know this is not a forum of debugging. I didn't ask just for waste the time of people. I think it's important to know what happens: if I'm doing some form in which there are some unnamed input. know if there are data tranfers (and so, there's more time to wait) may require to change the solution. Thinking well, my question is not a stupid question.

Comment: DEAR @Bondye i wrote stupid as too much simple for who know well html POST and GET. Don't be so rush.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does form data still transfer if the input tag has no name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543848/does-form-data-still-transfer-if-the-input-tag-has-no-name)

Answer (score 1):

No, they won't get the data. `id` is optional, but for PHP to do anything it requires the `name` attribute.

Comment: yes, this is the point: PHP require name to build the array $_POST. But I think that it's the browser (client-side) who determine what to send what to not, or i'm wrong? @gerben-jacobs

Comment: I would like clarification on this as well.  Is there any method for accessing unnamed inputs in PHP or any other web frameworks (say, Web2Py)?  Or is it just a part of the specification for most if not all modern web browsers that unnamed inputs not be passed in the request to the server in the first place a hence no frameworks support it?

Comment: Yep, you're both right. The browser won't know (and according to spec as well) how to send those inputs, so it doesn't.