# HTML5 form isn’t submitting any data

Tags: html, forms, post, submit

I’ve got the following HTML5 form:

```
  <form action="/desired_worktimes/submit" method="post">
    <div class="month">
      <h2>October</h2>
      <div class="week">
        <h3>2013-10-21–2013-10-21</h3>    
        <p>
          <span>Mon</span>

          <label for="from-2013-10-21">From</label>
          <input type="time" id="from-2013-10-21" />

          <label for="to-2013-10-21">To</label>
          <input type="time" id="to-2013-10-21" />

          <label for="free-2013-10-21">Free</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="free-2013-10-21" />

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

When I hit submit, no data arrives at the post endpoint. I tested the server with [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm), it displays all form data submitted to the endpoint, but with the above form, I get nothing.

What is wrong with the form?

Comment: I don't see `name` attribute anywhere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does form data still transfer if the input tag has no name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543848/does-form-data-still-transfer-if-the-input-tag-has-no-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use `name` attribute for each input. Example: `<input type="time" id="from-2013-10-21" name="abc"/>`. To get the value of these input, just use `$_POST['abc']`.

Comment: Whoa. Now I remember wondering why I need the redundancy when reading the introduction to forms. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Check the last line of your code and also you have not included `name` attribute in any of your form fields:

Instead of this:

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

It should have been this:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Comment: If your using html5 then you can proceed with your syntax and ignore mine,though both are valid. But dont forget to enter the `name` attribute for all the form fields..:)