# Spread radio button inside table cell

Tags: html, css

I need to have table with two columns. Each row is one radio button pair.

For example: There is question and two possible answers yes/no.

```
+------+------+
| yes  | no   | - 1.question
| yes  | no   | - 2.question
| yes  | no   | - 3.question
| yes  | no   | - 4.question
| yes  | no   | - 5.question
+------+------+
```

The problem is I need to spread radio button to whole cell. If someone wants to select choice it is not comfortable to target only on text... How to do that

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="first">yes</radio>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="first">no</radio>
    </td>
    <td>
      1.Question
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="second">yes</radio>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="second">no</radio>
    </td>
    <td>
      2.Question
    </td>
  </tr>...
</table>
```

Comment: Please show us the HTML code, not just a draw...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<del>One issue with your HTML: you did not specify the `name` attribute for the input elements. Remember that if you're doing this, [no data will be sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543848/does-form-data-still-transfer-if-the-input-tag-has-no-name) because there is simply no fragment identifier for the form data.</del>

**OP seems to have fixed the issue for the missing `name` attribute.**

---

Use `<label for="...">` to target each radio button by `id` within the table cell, and set it to a block level element such that it fills up the entire space in the cell. Example markup:

```css
label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="q1-y"><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-y" value="yes" />Yes</label></td>
    <td><label for="q1-n"><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-n" value="no" />No</label></td>
    <td>Question 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See proof-of-concept demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/zrjy29bw/