# looping over listitems of a UL when LI are not runat=server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web component that is generating code such as:

```
<ul id="basic_tag_handler" runat="server">
  <li class="tagItem">one</li>
  <li class="tagItem">two</li>
  <li class="tagItem">now</li>
  <li class="tagInput"><input class="tagInputField" type="text"></li>
</ul>
```

How can i use c# to iterate and access the values of the dynamic items (added and removed client-side via java script) in the c# code-behind on post backs?

or else how can i get the value of the input field "tagInputField"

I am trying this without luck:

```
lblData.Text = Request.Form["tagInputField"].ToLower();
```

I also tried somethign liek this:

```
foreach (Control item in this.form.Controls)
{
    //We just need HtmlInputCheckBox 
    HtmlInputText _txt = item as HtmlInputText;
    if (_txt != null)
    {
        lblData.Text = _txt.Value;
    }
}
```

I am not able to edit the markup of the html and am looking for a way to iterate over the request object to get at all the form elements and pick only the LI items of the UL id="basic_tag_handler"

Answer (score 1):

Give your input element a name:

```
<input name="tagInputField" class="tagInputField" type="text">
```

You can now get it from the Form data array:

```
lblData.Text = Request.Form["tagInputField"].ToLower();
```

Comment: and if i can not give it a name? how do i iterate over the request object to get at all the form elements and pick only the LI items of the UL id="basic_tag_handler"

Comment: @kacalapy - If the element does not have a name, it's value will never make it to the server, in which case your C# will not be able to process it. See [Does form data still transfer if the input tag has no name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543848/does-form-data-still-transfer-if-the-input-tag-has-no-name). Your only option would be to dynamically create a hidden input element via Javascript and copy the value (or dynamically add a name attribute to the input element).

Comment: good to know! how can you dynamically add a name in java script? i am guessing prior to the post back so the server would have it ?

Comment: I'd use jQuery's [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) function, but how and when to add the attribute is going to be highly dependent on your product.