# Can't retrieve POST data using node.js v0.12.7, express 4, body-parser, bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, body-parser

I've done this dozens of times in previous apps but for some reason can't get it working any more.  Not sure if it's a version issue or not.  I've looked at every example I could find online and none of it is working.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Relevant code:

**index.html** (copied from bootstrap site - I only added the role, action, and method attrs to the form tag)

```
<html>

  <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form role="form" action="/form" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bp = require("body-parser");
var path = require("path");

app.use(bp.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bp.json());

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
});

app.post("/form", function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.end();
});

var server = app.listen(4000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.13.3",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "sqlite3": "^3.0.10"
  }
}
```

When the form route gets called, `req.body` is always `{}`.  This same setup has worked for me every time in the past though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form `input` elements are missing `name` attributes and are therefore not being included with the POST request. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12543907/2039244).