# Twitter typeahead not preserving value after user selects an option

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I am trying to optimize a dropdown selection bar to typeahead autocomplete using twitter's typeahead. When I implemented twitter's typeahead, I couldn't preserve the value which user selected or type it after refreshing the page. Also, when I try to submit the form I am working on, it seems like it's never recorded as a value field.

### This is my code :

**Substring matcher for autocomplete and suggestion**

```
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
          return function findMatches(q, cb) {
            var matches, substringRegex;
            matches = [];
            substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
            jQuery(function ($){
                  $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
                      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                          matches.push(str);
                      }
                  });
                  cb(matches);
              });
          };
    };
```

**Typeahead**

```
 var Array = [];
        jQuery(function ($) {
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#project').typeahead({
                                hint: true,
                                highlight: true,
                                minLength: 1
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'Projects',
                                source: substringMatcher(Array)
                            });
                });

            });
```

**html**

```
<c:forEach items="${Form.projectList}" var="val">
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var Projects = "${val.project}";
        Array.push(Projects);
   </script>
</c:forEach>

<div id="the-basics">
   <input id = "project" class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Projects">
</div>
```

Can anyone give me any suggestions on how I should figure out this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> … when I try to submit the form I am working on, it seems like it's never recorded as a value field.

Your `input` element is missing a `name` attribute, which [is required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12543848/578288) for the `input`’s value to be sent when the form is submitted. Try using this HTML:

```html
<input id="project" name="project" class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Projects">
```

I am not sure if this will also solve the problem where the value is lost when the page refreshes, or if that requires an additional solution.

Comment: @thomas101rcx Since my answer worked, please [accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Also upvote my answer if “this answer is useful”. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).