# @ModelAttribute fields are null in Spring controller

Tags: java, forms, jsp, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I followed a tutorial to handle form submission in Spring. I wanted to populate my `TaskEntity` bean with the form and have this bean's values available in my controller's `taskSubmit` method. However, all of the properties of `task` in this method are null when I fill out the form and hit submit. The relevant code is as follows:

**TaskEntity.java**

```
public class TaskEntity {

    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Date dueDate;
    private TaskPriority priority;

    public void setTitle(String title) 
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() 
    {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) 
    {
        this.description = description;
    }


    public String getDescription() 
    {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDueDate(Date dueDate) 
    {
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
    }

    public Date getDueDate() 
    {
        return this.dueDate;
    }

    public void setPriority(String priority) 
    {
        this.priority = TaskPriority.valueOf(priority);
    }

    public TaskPriority getPriority() 
    {
        return this.priority;
    }
}
```

**addTask.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>To Do List - Add Task</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="tasks" th:action="@{/tasks}" th:object="${taskEntity}" method="post">
        <p>Title: <input type="text" th:field="*{title}" /></p>
        <p>Description: <input type="text" th:field="*{description}" /></p>
        <p>Due Date: <input type="text" th:field="*{dueDate}" /></p>
        <p>Priority: <input type="text" th:field="*{priority}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**TaskController.java**

```
@Controller
public class TaskController {

    private static final String TASKS = "/tasks";
    private static final String ADD_TASK = "/addTask";

    @Autowired
    private TaskEntityDao taskEntityDao;

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @RequestMapping(value = TASKS, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView readTasks() 
    {
        return new ModelAndView("tasks");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = ADD_TASK, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addTask(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("taskEntity", new TaskEntity());
        return "addTask";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = TASKS, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void taskSubmit(@ModelAttribute TaskEntity task)
    {
        // Fields for 'task' are all null!      
        taskEntityDao.createTask(task);

        readTasks();
    }
}
```

I expected the `TaskEntity` passed to the view with `model.addAttribute("taskEntity", new TaskEntity());` was going to have the form values mapped to it's fields, but I must have missed something.

**Update:**

I am adding the view resolver code from my Spring config:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Comment: What if you add the `model.addAttribute("taskEntity", new TaskEntity());` to the readTasks() method?

Comment: Please post your Spring MVC configuration, at least the `ViewResolver`(s).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've updated my question, thanks

Comment: `Thymeleaf` does not work with a `UrlBasedViewResolver`, it has its own `ViewResolver` for `Thymeleaf`, furthermore, `Thymeleaf` works with a `.html` file, not with `.jsp`. Could you post the final html code generated in your web browser from `addTask.jsp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your edit you've confirmed that your view resolution is for JSPs.

You have a JSP page with `<input>` elements that look like

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{description}" />
```

Presumably `th:field` is a [Thymeleaf element](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#inputs), but your page isn't processed by Thymeleaf, it's processed by the JSP Servlet. The JSP Servlet doesn't care about `th:field`, it's not special to it in any way. It just copies it literally. Furthermore, your `input` doesn't have a `name` attribute. [As such, when you submit the `form`, your browser doesn't send a corresponding value.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543848/does-form-data-still-transfer-if-the-input-tag-has-no-name) (Even if it did, it wouldn't have a name that Spring MVC recognizes and can bind to your model attribute.)

Set up your MVC configuration to properly render Thymeleaf views instead of JSP views.

Or if you really want to use JSPs, use the corresponding technologies: EL, JSTL, and Spring's tag library. There are tons of tutorials online, like [this one](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial).

Comment: Is there any way I can avoid the need for Thymeleaf and just POST from a simple form in my JSP page?

Comment: @petehallw Of course. Use JSP features like EL and the JSTL. Spring also comes with its own tag library.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `GET`/`POST` for the same URL, in this case represented by `TASKS = "/tasks"`

Thus according with the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = TASKS, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView readTasks() 
{
    return new ModelAndView("tasks");
}
```

Where was created the `TaskEntity` object?

You have `model.addAttribute("taskEntity", new TaskEntity());` in the `addTask` method, but works with **other** URL, in this case `ADD_TASK = "/addTask"`.

You need understand that the web form is loaded according a model created through the `GET` event and then when the submit event happens (web form was filled) the `POST` event happens. In this scenario is normal that `GET`/`POST` (handled by `@RequestMapping` ) share the 'same' URL.

**Observation:** `Thymeleaf` does not work with a `UrlBasedViewResolver`, it has its own `ViewResolver` for `Thymeleaf`, furthermore, `Thymeleaf` works with a `.html` file, not with `.jsp`. Thus I am *assuming* the `POST` event is not working how should be expected for the `Model`.

**Note**: is a bad practice that a `@Controller` has a direct dependency with a `@Repository`, it should be for a `@Service`.

According with:

```
@RequestMapping(value = TASKS, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void taskSubmit(@ModelAttribute TaskEntity task)
{
    // Fields for 'task' are all null!      
    taskEntityDao.createTask(task);

    readTasks();
}
```

- For `Fields for 'task' are all null!`, how you are confirming that?
- Consider in remove `readTasks()`. Is not very common that a `@RequestMapping` calls other `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: I appreciate your comments on bad practice, I am new to this and you're probably correct there. However I don't think this is actually an answer to my question. The bit about Thymeleaf may be relevant but I don't believe I'm confusing the URL's. I navigate to the form via /addTask and the form POST's to /task. The other /task method, `readTasks()`, is not relevant to my question but is used to GET the tasks from the database.