# None value passed on editing the form on HTML

Tags: python, django

I am editing the Firtname and Lastname fetched from auth_User. When I edit the name and save, the None value is passed to the names. On verifying page source I dont see any error.

*form.py*

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name', 'email')
```

*view.py*

```
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user,
                                 data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Profile updated successfully!')
        else:
            messages.success(request, 'Error updating your profile!')
    else:
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request,
                  'account/edit.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form})
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="form-row">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" placeholder="First Name">First Name:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" value="{{ user_form.first_name.value }}">
              </div>
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" value="{{ user_form.last_name.value }}">
              </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
              <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email address:</label>{{ user_form.email }}
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="{{ user_form.email.value }}">
              </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<input>` tags you have created in your template do not include `name` attributes. When you attempt to submit the form, these items [will not be sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543848/does-form-data-still-transfer-if-the-input-tag-has-no-name).

The correct `name` for each form field can be accessed using the `html_name` attribute, eg:

```
{{ user_form.first_name.html_name }}
```

@solarissmoke mentioned that you should consider using the Django form helpers, and I strongly agree. If you don't like how default widgets appear in your HTML, you can add classes when you create the form:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name', 'email')
        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

Then in your template:

```
<div class="form-row">
  <label for="{{ user_form.first_name.auto_id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label" placeholder="First Name">First Name:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    {{ user_form.first_name }}
  </div>
  <label for="{{ user_form.last_name.auto_id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    {{ user_form.last_name }}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <label for="{{ user_form.email.auto_id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email address:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    {{ user_form.email }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, MattRowbum for explaining so clearly, your answer helped me in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have any `name` attributes on your form fields, so no data will be submitted. Add a `name` attribute to both fields:

```
<input name="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" value="{{ user_form.first_name.value }}" > 
  <!-- ^^^^ note new name attribute -->
```

and:

```
<input name="last_name" type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" value="{{ user_form.last_name.value }}" >
```

Note also that you have specified `email` in the fields on your form, but there is no `email` field in your HTML, which will also cause problems. You should either add that field to your HTML or remove it from the form definition.

You might also consider using Django's [form helpers to render the fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

Comment: In my code I am extending the default user model that Django provides and also I tried the following code on HTML.   

    <label for="firstt_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name:</label>{{ user_form.first_name }}  

The value is fetched from the database and is displayed and also it saves if I edit but I don't get it in a proper format. The look of the default input field doesn't look good.

Comment: Okay - then you need to add `name` attributes as described in the answer.

Comment: When you say the name, do you mean this? Sorry I am new to Django.  

`class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
 first_name = forms.CharField()
 last_name = forms.CharField()
 email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name', 'email')`

Comment: No, I mean the HTML `name` attribute. I've tried to point it out as clearly as I can in the answer.