# Not getting entered data from input element

Tags: javascript, html, electron

[image]This is js app in electron framework. I am trying to get the updated text entered inside text box as shown in image but I am not able to retrieve any data. I have ensured that data is submitted. I have predefined data in a file ,initally, I have this values but onform submit, I modify those values.

```
function setData()
{
  let server = mapServers[i];

  var htmlForThisHostID = '<tr>';

  htmlForThisHostID += '<td class="hostid-td-padding">';
  htmlForThisHostID += "<input id=\"first\" type=\"text\" size=\"40\" 
 value=\""+server.name+"\"></input>";

  htmlForThisHostID += "</td>\n";
  htmlForThisHostID += '<td class="hostid-td-padding">';
  htmlForThisHostID += "<input type=\"text\" size=\"6\" value=\" 
  "+server.pin+" \"></input>";

  htmlForThisHostID += "</td>"; 
  htmlForThisHostID += '<td class="hostid-td-padding">';  
  htmlForThisHostID += "<input style=\"width:50px;\" type=\"submit\" 
 value=\"Save\" onclick='Activate(\"" + server.name + "\"," + server.pin + ")'></input>\n";
  htmlForThisHostID += "</td>";

  htmlForThisHostID += "</tr>\n";

  return htmlForThisHostID;
}
```

Comment: If this is your acutal code, all the line breaks within the strings are syntax errors

Comment: Hi bambam, but I am able to print fetched values from file for server,name and server.pin

Comment: you say "I am trying to get the updated text entered inside text box as shown in image but I am not able to retrieve any data." What image? Where and how are you trying to retrieve the data? Please post more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are letting the form submit itself with the inputs from your function, then the problem is that you have not set a name attribute for those inputs. Just give them a name.

Unnamed inputs do not get processed see this answer for further details https://stackoverflow.com/a/12543907/6127393