# Input form attribute not connecting to form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Whenever I click the submit button (save button here), the form sends a post request, but there is no data in the form, which it should be.

The form actually has 3 inputs: the text input, the file input, and the submit input. I'm using a flask backend and when i print out request.form and request.files, nothing is showing in the dictionary.

```html
<form action="" id="realForm1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" form="realForm1" class="form-control col-8 col-md-6" id="createANameInput" style="border-radius: 0;">
  <input type="file" id="realInput" form="realForm1">
  <input type="submit" id="hiddenButton">
</form>
```

I expect to see the data show up when I print out request.form or request.files, but it's not showing up at all!

Comment: Where are the name attributes of your input fields?

Comment: I am not able to see JS code. Can you share Js code too. Submitting the form will only accept name attribute of form element.

Answer (score 1):

As per **[W3C Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls)**:

> Every successful control/field has its control **name** paired with
>   its current **value** as part of the submitted form **data set**. A
>   successful control must be defined within a FORM element and must have
>   a control **name**.

The algorithm to **construct the form data set** for a form is mentioned in this [W3C Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-the-form-data-set).

Only the fields that have name attribute are submitted.

- Here is a similar question:

[Does form data still transfer if the input tag has no name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543848/does-form-data-still-transfer-if-the-input-tag-has-no-name)

- Further Reading

[Disabled form inputs do not appear in the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-the-request/7357314#7357314)

Comment: Thank you...this is exactly what I was missing