# Trying to check if user exists in my database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to check if user exists in my SQL Server database, but if user exists, or not, I always get the same response (redirection
to `~/korisnik/Korisnikkp`. Can someone help me? P**roblem is compiler doesn't get username value with this @0. Do you know how to fix that? If i hardcode user with examle 'nicolas55' it works.**
Thanks

```
    if (IsPost)
{
    var Username = "";
    var Password = "";
    Username = Request.Form["Username"];
    Password = Request.Form["Password"];
    if (Username != "" && Password != "")
    {
        var db = Database.Open("Useri");
        var command = @"SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username = @Username"; //when I put here 'nikola55' it works
        var result = db.QueryValue(command, Username);


        if (result != null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/korisnik/Korisnikkp");
        }
        else
        {
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("No user in database");
            </script>
        }
```

Form code:

```
<form method="post">
                        <!-- to error: add class "has-danger" -->

                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">username</label>
                        <input type="text" value="@Username">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                        <a href="#" style="float:right;font-size:12px;">Forgot password?</a>
                        <input type="password" value="@Password">

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>

                        <div class="sign-up">
                            Don't have an account? <a href="/korisnik">Create One</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the application and watching the content of the 'end' variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227148/discussion-between-nikola-stankovic-and-mjwills).

Comment: You showed us the code with hardcoded username which as you say works correctly. Please show the code that doesn't work for you so we can try to fix it

Comment: `<input type="text" value="@Username">` You forgot to set the `name` of the textbox to `Username`. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp The same for password.

Comment: It works with this line of code, but When i pass the parameter @Username, it won't work.

Comment: `@Username` should be @0 - https://forums.asp.net/t/1738717.aspx?Parameterized+Queries+in+Razor+Syntax+or+Method+to+Block+Special+Characters

Comment: @MiroslavZadravec Stop suggesting `SqlParameter`. They aren't needed here. https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/webmatrix.data.database.queryvalue?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2 The main (well, first) issue here is that `Username` is `null` - since the OP didn't set the same of the `input`.

Comment: @mjwills Good bless you, finally  IT WORKS! The answer was that I forgot to put NAME parameter in input. Please write your answer, so I can accept it here.

Comment: Next time, debug the code and inspect values using the Watch Window or Immediate Window or the debugger. You then would have realised that `Username` was `null` and thus focused in on the _real_ problem.

Comment: @mjwills Okay, thanks. Sorry, this is for my personal project , because I want to get a job. I am begginer.

Comment: All good - learning is part of the fun. ;)

Comment: @mjwills How to close this question?

Comment: Someone should mark a duplicate for this question (likely https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543848/does-form-data-still-transfer-if-the-input-tag-has-no-name).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you looked in docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/webmatrix.data.database.queryvalue?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2 you would see that Database.QueryValue `Executes a SQL query that returns a single scalar value as the result.`

So it will always return some object. It should not be null. So you have to check value of that object instead of return value of QueryValue

Comment: I would like to return how many rows are affected with my query. I used query,execute, but always the same response.

Comment: @NikolaStankovic, Database.QueryValue will always return single scalar value as a result. If you want to find out number of rows affected then you will have to use different method of Database. Use Database.Execute or Database.Query. Database.Execute will return count of records affected and Database.Query will return rows that you can count.

Comment: I will edit my code here soon, but i have used that, but still not working.

Comment: @mjwills You are right, but what to use rather than Select?

Comment: @mjwills I will try! Thanks

Comment: Problem is compiler doesn't get username value with this @0. Do you know how to fix that? If i hardcode user with examle 'nicolas55' it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
if ((object)end != DBNull.Value)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/korisnik/Korisnikkp");
}
else
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("No user in database");
    </script>
}
```